# Select column names based on condition in two separate table and database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have the same table in two separate database (schema can be different so I use 'intersect') :

- MyTable from Database1
- MyTable from Database2

I want to get the column name, and if possible data, when the row of the current column has NULL value in Database1 and NOT NULL in Database2.

The query can looks like this :

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM Database1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='MyTable' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM Database2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='MyTable' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
) /* +data ? */
FROM Database1.dbo.MyTable AS MyTable1 INNER JOIN
Database2.dbo.MyTable AS MyTable2 ON MyTable1.id = MyTable2.id
WHERE MyTable1.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL AND MyTable2.COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL
OR MyTable2.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL AND MyTable1.COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

But this is obviously wrong.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry it's SQL Server 2008

Comment: You seriously need to have a discussion about upgrading your sql server. 2008 has been out of support for several years. There are versions of sql server newer than yours that are no longer supported. This is like continuing to run Win95 because you never bothered to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers, unfortunately this is a client requirement so I cannot upgrade the version

Comment: Do you not know the names of the columns in your tables? If you truly don't know then you are going down the path of dynamic sql. Buckle up, that is a long bumpy ride for the inexperienced.

Comment: Sometimes our clients do not know they have seriously antiquated software. The hire people to help them because they don't know how to do it. Often times having that discussion with a client will result in them agreeing to upgrading it and thus getting you more work hours.

Comment: I know the tables but I need to filter them to get only columns which satisfy the where clause in my query. Indeed, I'm not familiar with dynamic SQL...

Comment: They plan to upgrade the system but not immediatly so I'm stuck with my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for this, and it won't be pretty.

```
DECLARE @sql     nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT t1.id',
        @sel     nvarchar(max) = N'', 
        @clauses nvarchar(max) = N'';
  
;WITH src(col, name) AS
(
      SELECT QUOTENAME(c.name), c.name 
        FROM Database1.sys.columns AS c
        INNER JOIN Database1.sys.tables AS t
        ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
        WHERE t.name = N'MyTable' AND t.schema_id = 1
      INTERSECT 
      SELECT QUOTENAME(c.name), c.name 
        FROM Database2.sys.columns AS c
        INNER JOIN Database2.sys.tables AS t
        ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
        WHERE t.name = N'MyTable' AND t.schema_id = 1
),
clauses(clause, sel) AS
(
  SELECT clause = char(13) + char(10)
      + N'  OR (   (t1.' + col + N' IS NULL AND t2.' + col + N' IS NOT NULL)'
      + char(13) + char(10) 
      + '       OR (t1.' + col + N' IS NOT NULL AND t2.' + col + N' IS NULL))',
    sel = N',' + char(13) + char(10) 
      + N'  t1_' + name + N' = t1.' + col 
      + N', t2_' + name + N' = t2.' + col
  FROM src
  WHERE name <> N'id'
)
SELECT @sel += sel, @clauses += clause FROM clauses;
  
SELECT @sql += @sel 
   + char(13) + char(10) + N' FROM Database1.dbo.MyTable AS t1'
   + char(13) + char(10) + N' INNER JOIN Database2.dbo.MyTable AS t2'
   + char(13) + char(10) + N' ON t1.id = t2.id AND (1 = 2' + @clauses + N');';
  
SELECT @sql;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Output (assuming `MyTable` has common columns `id`, `x`, and `y`):

```
SELECT t1.id,
  t1_x = t1.[x], t2_x = t2.[x],
  t1_y = t1.[y], t2_y = t2.[y]
 FROM Database1.dbo.MyTable AS t1
 INNER JOIN Database2.dbo.MyTable AS t2
 ON t1.id = t2.id AND (1 = 2
  OR (   (t1.[x] IS NULL AND t2.[x] IS NOT NULL)
       OR (t1.[x] IS NOT NULL AND t2.[x] IS NULL))
  OR (   (t1.[y] IS NULL AND t2.[y] IS NOT NULL)
       OR (t1.[y] IS NOT NULL AND t2.[y] IS NULL)));
```

Comment: I will adapt this to my code thank you !